# Cannot `pip install numpy` on OS X Yosemite

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pandas, osx-yosemite

I am unable to `pip install pandas` or `pip install numpy` after having upgraded to OS X Yosemite. Both commands worked fine before. When I run

`$ pip install numpy`

the compile process runs for about 30 seconds and then I get this:

compiling C sources

```
C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe



creating build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/numpy/linalg

creating build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite

compile options: '-DATLAS_INFO="\"3.9.35\"" -I/opt/local/include -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -c'

cc: numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/python_xerbla.c

cc: numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.c

/usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -arch x86_64 -Wall -g -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/python_xerbla.o -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.1 -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7 -llapack -lptf77blas -lptcblas -latlas -lgfortran -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so

ld: symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not found, normally in crt1.o/dylib1.o/bundle1.o for architecture x86_64

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

ld: symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not found, normally in crt1.o/dylib1.o/bundle1.o for architecture x86_64

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: Command "/usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -arch x86_64 -Wall -g -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/python_xerbla.o -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.1 -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7 -llapack -lptf77blas -lptcblas -latlas -lgfortran -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so" failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Users/admin/.virtualenvs/numpy_env/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/admin/.virtualenvs/numpy_env/build/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/5b/1l8zg39d48d865bktn00qnbr0000gn/T/pip-yQOlkU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/admin/.virtualenvs/numpy_env/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/admin/.virtualenvs/numpy_env/build/numpy
Storing debug log for failure in /var/folders/5b/1l8zg39d48d865bktn00qnbr0000gn/T/tmpuDgjp9
```

I have tried upgrading Python, recreating my virtualenv, restarting my system, and banging my head on the desk, but none have helped. I also ran `brew rm gfortran` followed by `brew install gcc`, but that didn't help.

Comment: I'm not sure what might be the real issue behind this, but will it be possible for you to install the Anaconda distribution instead? My experience with their distribution is that the SciPy stack is almost always guaranteed to work, regardless of OS.

Comment: @ericmjl anaconda is fine but it does not solve the same problem for people who want to build from source, e.g. the development branch to test a bug fix before issuing a pull request.

Comment: Also `pip install numpy` on OSX 10.9 uses the binary wheel package so no build step is required. This does not work in 10.10 because of the strict platform tag checks of pip and the filenames of the macosx wheels published at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.8.1 . future versions of pip might fix that and allow forward compat in OSX platform tags.

Comment: Tim: you should move your update as an answer and mark it as valid (green tick) after the cool down period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the recommendation of [someone on twitter](https://twitter.com/Hyperion_HQ/status/527813954282979328), I ran `brew uninstall gcc`. This caused the numpy install to use `gcc` as provided by XCode. This seems to work fine.

Homebrew installs gc 4.9 while Apple is on 4.2.1. However, I don't know what the underlying issue is.